# "Invalid reply from server" when accessing a function from another CFC using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

One of the pages in my application, using Application.cfc, calls a function defined in an Ajax.cfc file using JavaScript (DWREngine) to populate a drop down on page load. When I load that page, I get an error saying "invalid response from server" and the drop down does not populate.

For the function in Ajax.cfc, the access attribute is set to "remote".

I'm not sure why the response is not sent back by the ajax file.
Let me know if you need anything else to answer my question.

Update (sorry for being late):
I added this piece of code in onRequestStart method in Application.cfc:

```
<cfif ListLast(CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH, ".") is "cfc">
   <cfset StructDelete(this,'onRequest')>
</cfif>
```

onRequest method causes Ajax failures when called from another CFC in same/sub directories. I also need onRequest and Ajax so found this workaround.

Comment: Can you just enter the ajax URL right into your browser. What happens. Also, can you post the code that is relevant to the remote method including the URL format, function creation etc.

Comment: As @leeish said - try entering the request in your browser directly bypassing the Javvascript.  Like "ajax.cfc?method=myMethod&argument1=blah&argument2=blah" - that will allow you to debug the method call. Once you get it sorted, plug it back into your ajax engine.

Comment: @Leeish thanks for the reply. I have updated the description on how i handled the issue. Ajax.cfc's method is working fine through browser as well as when using Application.cfm. Problem started after i started using Application.cfc.
The remote method returns a result set in the form of a query output which will be converted to wddx and used to populate a drop down.
Any other workaround/alternative approach you can suggest?
I'm not connected to my work network now so cannot give you the info you need.

Comment: @MarkAKruger thanks for your comments. please check my above reply.

Comment: Check a few things. 1) does the folder containing the CFC have it's own Application.cfc? 2) are you using onRequest() (or maybe it's "onRequeststart()" - these functions sometimes scramble cfc remote requests. 3) consider using JSON instead of WDDX - it's leaner and JS libraries understand it universally.

Comment: @MarkAKruger 1)The application with Application.cfc has a sub folder which consists the Ajax.cfc file.
2) I'm using both the functions.
3) Yes, we are slowly changing to jquery and will use JSON as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this piece of code in onRequestStart method in Application.cfc:

```
<cfif ListLast(CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH, ".") is "cfc">
   <cfset StructDelete(this,'onRequest')>
</cfif>
```

onRequest method is known to cause Ajax failures when called from another CFC in same/sub directories. I also need onRequest and Ajax so found this workaround.

Comment: There is an optional `onCFCRequest` method as part of Application.cfc. Perhaps you could use that method instead of checking for the file extension. Seems cleaner to me. [The docs for it are here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe821657cd7d6f83f6daaa733122cf6931bb-8000.html)

Comment: Not clear what CF version he's using ... onCFCRequest is fairly new (CF11?) ]

Comment: Thanks @Miguel-F for your reply. Sorry i could not reply to you earlier as i was on vacation for the last 12 days. I have not really seen much of onCFCRequest method. Is it available in newer versions? I was using CF 8 and now going to migrate to CF 9. Thanks for the docs link.

Answer (score 1):

In your workaround, 'this' refers to the component Application.cfc, which is not a structure. What you want is the structure, variables, hence

```
<cfset StructDelete(variables,'onRequest')>
```

Comment: Thanks @BKBK for your reply. Sorry i could not reply to you earlier as i was on vacation for the last 12 days.
Using "this" worked as well. What you say may be correct.
My understanding for using "this" and it working is since "this" refers to entire component(including methods) and there is only one onRequest method it was able to find it. What do you think?